# Finding a limit of a matrix raised to the $n$-th power

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, stochastic-processes

There is a stochastic matrix given
$$\mathbb{P} = \begin{bmatrix} 0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ \frac{1}{2}&0&0&\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3} \end{bmatrix}$$
I am to find $\mathbb{P}^n$. I know a theorem which says that if $\exists n$ $[p_{i,j}^n] >0$ then the limit exists and can be easily calculated (of course by $[p_{i,j}^n]$ I mean elements of $\mathbb{P}^n$).

In my case however $[p_{2,1}^n] = [p_{2,3}^n] = [p_{2,4}^n] =0, \forall n$. How can I solve this problem? Is there another theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State $2$ is absorbing and the other three states are all transient (because they all lead to state $2$). Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_{ij}^{n}=0$ if $j \neq 2$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_{ij}^{n}=1$ if $j = 2$.

Comment: Does it mean that if one state is absorbing then the limit will always look like the one that was written by you? (One columns of ones and the rest full of zeros )

Comment: For all j? But such a matrix wouldn't be stochastic then, would it?

Comment: Look at the identity matrix.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

We [have](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=JordanDecomposition%5B%7B%7B0,+1%2F2,+1%2F2,+0%7D,+%7B0,+1,+0,+0%7D,+%7B1%2F2,+0,+0,+1%2F2%7D,+%7B1%2F3,+0,+1%2F3,+1%2F3%7D%7D%5D) $P=SDS^{-1}$, where
$$
S=\pmatrix{               
-1 & -1 & \frac{9}{16} & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & \frac{15}{16} & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
}
,\quad
D=\pmatrix{
-\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
}
$$
Therefore, $P^\infty = S D^\infty S^{-1}$.
Since
$$
D^\infty = \pmatrix{
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
}
$$
we have
$$
P^\infty = \pmatrix{
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
}
$$